# Apply Python lambda : if condition giving syntax error

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, lambda, pandas-apply

This is my data set

```
fake_abalone2

   Sex   Length  Diameter  Height   Whole  Shucked  Viscera  Shell  Rings
                                    Weight  Weight  Weight  Weight
0   M    0.455    0.365    0.095    0.5140  0.2245  0.1010  0.1500  15
1   M    0.350    0.265    0.090    0.2255  0.0995  0.0485  0.0700  7
2   F    0.530    0.420    0.135    0.6770  0.2565  0.1415  0.2100  9
3   M    0.440    0.365    0.125    0.5160  0.2155  0.1140  0.1550  10
4   K    0.330    0.255    0.080    0.2050  0.0895  0.0395  0.0550  7
5   K    0.425    0.300    0.095    0.3515  0.1410  0.0775  0.1200  8
```

Getting syntax error while using the following method. Please help me out.
I want the value in "sex" table to change depending on "Rings" table.If "Rings" value is less than 10 the corresponding "sex" value should be changed to 'K'.Otherwise, no change should be made in "Sex" table.

```
 fake_abalone2["sex"]=fake_abalone2["Rings"].apply(lambda x:"K" if x<10)
```

> File "", line 1
>           fake_abalone2["sex"]=fake_abalone2["Rings"].apply(lambda x:"K" if x<10)
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please format your question, don't forget to read the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.

Comment: What should be the output of the lambda if `x >= 10`?

Comment: for x>=10 there sholud not be any change in column "Sex"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Python numpy instead of lambda function.

Import python numpy using `import numpy as np`

then you can use the following method to replace the string.

```
fake_abalone2['Sex'] = np.where(fake_abalone2['Rings']<10, 'K', fake_abalone2['Sex'])
```

Comment: This method works well.But, is it wise to load Numpy Library just to use where method?

Answer (score 3):

The Following method works perfectly.

```
    df1["Sex"]=df1.apply(lambda x: "K"if x.Rings<10 else x["Sex"],axis=1)
```

df1 is the dataframe

```
  Sex   Length  Diameter Height Whole   Shucked Viscera Shell Rings         
                                weight  weight  weight  weight
0   M   0.455   0.365   0.095   0.5140  0.2245  0.1010  0.1500  15
1   K   0.350   0.265   0.090   0.2255  0.0995  0.0485  0.0700  7
2   K   0.530   0.420   0.135   0.6770  0.2565  0.1415  0.2100  9
3   M   0.440   0.365   0.125   0.5160  0.2155  0.1140  0.1550  10
4   K   0.330   0.255   0.080   0.2050  0.0895  0.0395  0.0550  7
5   K   0.425   0.300   0.095   0.3515  0.1410  0.0775  0.1200  8
6   F   0.530   0.415   0.150   0.7775  0.2370  0.1415  0.3300  20
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is the output of the lambda function:

```
.apply(lambda x:"K" if x<10)
```

The output is not certain for other conditions, so you can use **else** something ...

```
.apply(lambda x:"K" if x<10 else None)
```